# How to use GdkPixbuf with wxpython?

Tags: wxpython, gdkpixbuf

Is it possible to convert it into bitmap or icon?
I'd like to avoid saving it in file and read it with wx.Bitmap, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import wx
import gtk

pb = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("someFile.jpg")
img = wx.EmptyImage(pb.get_width(), pb.get_height())
img.SetData(pb.get_pixels())
## you can now convert the wx.Image to wx.Bitmap etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for answers.. but one thing. Why pb length is 4096 and img is 3072 so i get error about differ size? Is is something with alpha?